# How to eliminate the round trip for find and update sequence relying on graphql generated api

Tags: graphql, faunadb

Is it possible to call graphql query and mutation from within UDF for example to call find and update operations in sequence without the round trip to server to extract ID from find result to feed it to update call?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of a question on Fauna's forums: https://forums.fauna.com/t/find-and-update-in-auto-generated-graphql-api/3205

To copy that answer here:

---

GraphQL does let you make multiple queries in a single request.

```
query {
  thing1: findThingByID(id: "1234") { _id, _ts, field }
  thing2: findThingByID(id: "5555") { _id, _ts, field }
}
```

That's not a Fauna thing, rather it is part of how GraphQL works.  https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases

These are run at the same time, though.  If you need to use the response from one request in the body of the next request then GraphQL does not have a mechanism for this.  You can, however, create a UDF and call it with a customer resolver.

```
type Query {
  myAdvancedQuery(thing1: ID, thing2: ID): [SomeResultType] @resolver
}
```

```js
CreateFunction({
  name: "myAdvancedQuery",
  role: Role("myAdvancedQueryFnRole") // https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/security/abac
  body: Query(
    Lambda(
      ["thing1", "thing2"],
      Let(
        {
          step1: /* Do something with thing 1 */
          step2: /* Do something with thing 2 */
          step3: /* Do something with the results of steps 1 and 2 */
        },
        /* create and return the payload that GraphQL expects */
      )
    )
  )
})
```

https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/directives/d_resolver